# modify Regular expression that will allow special characters only in double quotes

Tags: javascript

I have a  regular expression that checks the validity of local part of my mail.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&\'\*\+-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~\\\\\\"\']{1,64})$/
```

I want to include some additional logic in this regex so that it will check if special characters such as `()@[]:;,<>` are included in double quotes only.

I tried to merge this expression `/^\"<>()@[];:,\"$/` in my existing one above, but it is not validating correctly.

Can anyone please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: *"I tried to merge this expression"* How? We cannot tell you what you have done wrong if you don't post what you actually have done.

Comment: Ok this is what I have tried and is not validating correctly /^([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&\'\*\+-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~\\\\\\"\'\/^\"<>()@[];:,\"$\/]{1,64})$/

Comment: Please can anybody suggest a solution

Comment: Even the regex /^\\"()[]<>;:,\\"$/; seems to fail.please can anybody suggest a workaround

Comment: Can anybody please help :)